How to create a responsive circle with two lines of text in HTML and CSS?


body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 15px;
}

.circle {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 600;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}
<body>
  <div class="circle">
    <div>2</div>
    <div>AP</div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle">
    <div>200,000</div>
    <div>AP</div>
  </div>
</body>



Why is the aspect-ratio CSS property not working here? When the text inside is long enough (like if I use 200,000 instead of 2, it is a square aspect ratio perfect circle). But I need it to work when the text is short too.
I want to avoid Javascript and hardcoding any widths or heights, because the circle should be fully responsive to the text inside of it, and be the minimum size required to display it (while also being a square aspect ratio).

Define a min-height equal to 2 lines of content using 2lh


.circle {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 600;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  min-height: 2lh;
}


body {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  min-height:100vh;
}
<div class="circle">
  <div>20</div>
  <div>AP</div>
</div>




Thank you for the answer! Is there any way to do this with something that has better browser support (lh)? 88% is decent, but ideally a more universal solution exists

@RyanPeschel you can wait for more answers

Don t think it s possible

Giving it any old min-height makes a circle (at least on testing on iOS). So giving it 2em might give you a good enough result.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Responsive Circles with Text</title>
<style>
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .circle {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 40vw;
    height: 40vw;
    max-width: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #3498db;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.2;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="circle">Line 1</div>
  <div class="circle">Line 2</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>

